# How to write this query with the following schema?

Tags: mysql

I have the database schema as follows:

```
Teams(teamID,teamName,home,leagueName)
Games(gameID,homeTeamID,guestTeamID,date)
```

How can I query(using SQL)
all `teamID`s where the team played against the team1 but not against the team2. 'team1 and team2 are some data values in the column `teamName`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is no game without `HomeTeam` or `GuestTeam`. Try this one,

```
SELECT  a.gameID,
        b.TeamName AS HomeTeam,
        c.TeamName AS GuestTeam,
        a.`date`
FROM    GAMES a
        INNER JOIN Teams b
            ON a.homeTeamID = b.teamID
        INNER JOIN Teams c
            ON a.guestTeamID = c.teamID
WHERE   (
            b.TeamName = 'Team1' AND
            c.teamName <> 'Team2'
        )
        OR
        (
            c.TeamName = 'Team1' AND
            b.teamName <> 'Team2'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

> All teamIDs where the team played against the team1 but not against
>   the team2

```
SELECT t1.teamName AS 'Home', t2.TeamName AS 'Guest', g.Date
FROM
(
   SELECT *
   FROM Games
   WHERE (homeTeamID  = 'Team 1' OR guestTeamID  =  'Team 1')
     AND (homeTeamID <> 'Team 2' OR guestTeamID <> 'Team 1')
) g ON t.teamID = hg.homeTeamID
INNER JOIN teams t1 ON g.homeTeamID  = t1.teamId 
INNER JOIN teams t2 ON g.guestTeamID = t2.teamId
```